# Swagger ui not working for springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

Trying to enable swagger ui for my springboot application. Getting 404 when hitting the swagger-ui endpoint

Springboot version: 3.0.5
using: org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0

```
springdoc:
  pathsToMatch: /**
  api-docs:
    groups:
      enabled: true
    enabled: true
    path: /v3/api-docs
    version: openapi_3_0
  packagesToScan: com.flipkart.marketplace.infrastructure.adapter.web
  show-actuator: true
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
```

Infact no endpoint is working related to spring-docs. Getting 404 for all usecase

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain apiHttpSecurity(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .securityMatcher(new OrServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                        new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/**"),
                        new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/actuator/**")))
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .anyExchange()
                        //.authenticated()
                        .permitAll()
                );
        //.oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain webHttpSecurity(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers(
                                "/v3/api-docs/**", "/v3/api-docs.yaml", "/v3/api-docs.yaml/**",
                                "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/swagger-ui/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Also using default context path